# TYPO3: Access old-style piBase methods from Extbase extension

Tags: typo3, extbase, pibase

Can I access old-style **piBase** classes and methods from my Extbase extension?

For example, can I create an `AccessMyoldExtensionService.php` Service as a wrapper class and then pull the return values into my controller?

In my case, I need to return a list of old data records that can't be migrated to MVC style directly.

If so, what would the basic approach be?

Comment: Which methods do you need ? Do "data records" mean database records ?

Comment: I'd like to access functions of an individual extension, like `tx_myoldextension_pi1::listElements()` and/or the corresponding database records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get access on the db records of your old extension you can map the table into your new extension.
Create a new model with matching properties of the needed table fields.
Create the mapping in TS setup.txt like

```
persistence{
[...]
    classes{
        Tx_YourNewExtension_Domain_Model_Bar {
            mapping {
                tableName = tableNameOfOldExtension
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Create the related repository.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I actually ended up doing. Just forgot to update this question in time. Works nicely.